# Parsing a Json with JsonArray as a root using Retrofit

Tags: android, json, gson, retrofit

This is my Json. The problem with it is that it has an array as a node. I'm not that fluent with Retrofit and so I'm having some problems trying to understand what's going on and how to fix it.

```
[
{
    "first_name":"Jakub",
    "nickname":"",
    "last_name":"Machalek",
    "description":"description1",
    "speaker_id":0,
    "image_path":""
},
    {
    "first_name":"Krzysztof",
    "nickname":"",
    "last_name":"Opasik",
    "description":"Description2",
    "speaker_id":1,
    "image_path":""
},
...etc...
```

How am I supposed to parse it? My current try goes like this

POJOs

```
public class Speaker implements ParentListItem{
private String mFirstName;
private String mNickname;
private String mLastName;
private String mDescription;
private String mImageUrl;

private ArrayList<Speaker> mChildrenList;

public Speaker(String mFirstName, String mNickname, String mLastName, String mDescription, String mImageUrl) {
    this.mFirstName = mFirstName;
    this.mNickname = mNickname;
    this.mLastName = mLastName;
    this.mDescription = mDescription;
    this.mImageUrl = mImageUrl;
    mChildrenList = new ArrayList<>();
    mChildrenList.add(this);
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return mFirstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String mFirstName) {
    this.mFirstName = mFirstName;
}

public String getNickname() {
    return mNickname;
}

public void setNickname(String mNickname) {
    this.mNickname = mNickname;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return mLastName;
}

public void setLastName(String mLastName) {
    this.mLastName = mLastName;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return mDescription;
}

public void setDescription(String mDescription) {
    this.mDescription = mDescription;
}

public String getImageUrl() {
    return mImageUrl;
}

public void setImageUrl(String mImageUrl) {
    this.mImageUrl = mImageUrl;
}

@Override
public List<?> getChildItemList() {
    return mChildrenList;
}

@Override
public boolean isInitiallyExpanded() {
    return false;
}
```

And

```
public class SpeakerList {

List<Speaker> speakerList;


public List<Speaker> getSpeakerList() {
    return speakerList;
}

public void add(Speaker nataCenterItem){
    if(speakerList == null){
        speakerList = new LinkedList<>();
    }
    speakerList.add(nataCenterItem);
}
```

Retrofit
    public class SessionInfoService {
    private SessionInfoApi sessionInfoApi;

```
public SessionInfoService(){
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("...")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    sessionInfoApi = retrofit.create(SessionInfoApi.class);
}

public void getLectureList(Callback callback) throws IOException {
    sessionInfoApi.getLectureList().enqueue(callback);
}

public void getSpeakerList(Callback callback) throws IOException {
    sessionInfoApi.getSpeakerList().enqueue(callback);
}
```

Interface

```
@GET("...")
Call<List<Speaker>> getSpeakerList();
```

I could use any help.

Comment: I've accepted the answer below. Sorry for the delay. I was an occasional user. Now I'm starting to use SO more frequently at my job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell all looks good except you've missed something in your `Speaker` model. So as you've setup your retrofit instance, you're using the `gson` converter. By default `gson` serializes and deserializes the jsons by looking at the key in the json and trying to set the java object's attribute with the same name.

In your case, it tries to look for example for the attribute `first_name` in your `Speaker` model, which you don't have because it's `mFirstName`. So without any further assistance, `gson` cannot actually know which field to set in your model.

One obvious way to fix this is to name your field `first_name`. However, this is not the most common or desired way to name fields in Java, so `gson` offers you the `SerializedName` annotation. It basically tells which field in the json does the field in the Java object relate to. So if you'd write your `Speaker` model as:

```
public class Speaker implements ParentListItem{
  @SerializedName("first_name")
  private String mFirstName;
  @SerializedName("nickname")
  private String mNickname;
  @SerializedName("last_name")
  private String mLastName;
  // ...
}
```

then `gson` knows which fields to set and use to deserialize and serialize the json. The Retrofit call looks good. I guess you can ignore the `SpeakerList` model and use the `List<Speaker>` like you have.

You might consider using also the [Expose Annotation](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/annotations/Expose.html). It's not strictly necessary, but might be needed. From the docs:

> This annotation has no effect unless you build Gson with a GsonBuilder and invoke GsonBuilder.excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation() method.

Comment: Thank you. I was an ocassional SO user so it took me a while to accept this answer but as I can remember this is exactly what the problem was. Thank you for your answer man :)